# jQuery - adding checkboxes in a specific table

Tags: jquery

I'm stuck with my small jQuery script. 
I want to make checkboxes for the rows of a specific table.
This would be a greasemonkey script, so I can't edit the source of the site.

This is how the HTML is set up:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
     <table class = test1></table>
     <table class = test2></table>
     <table class = goal>
       <thead>
         some some <tr> 
       </thead>
       <tbody>
         here are the table rows where I want to put the checkboxes
       </tbody>
     </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem is that, is puts checkboxes in the rows at every "tr" what it can find in all the tables.
And finally my code:

```
var $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery

$(document).ready(function (){
  $("table.goal").ready(function(){
    $("tbody").ready(function(){
      $("tr").prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" name="x" value="y"></td>');
    });
  });
});
```

Please, someone would be so kind to explain me, why this isn't working as intended?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use table.ready/tbody.ready, you have to use [descendant-selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("table.goal tbody tr").prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" name="x" value="y"></td>');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8QaqE/)

Note: If the rows are created dynamically, then the dom manipulation need to be executed after the tr's are created

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("table.goal tbody tr").each(function(){
       //check if a checkbox is already added or not
       if($(this).find('td:eq(0) > input[type="checkbox"]').length)
       {
          $(this).prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" name="x" value="y"></td>');
       }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("tbody tr").prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" name="x" value="y"></td>');
```

It should omit the thead.

Answer (score 0):

```
Hope this might help you... :)  

    $(.goal tr).prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" name="x" value="y"></td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function AddCheckboxToTable($table) {
    var $thead = $table.find('> thead');
    var $tbody = $table.find('> tbody');

    $thead.find('> tr').prepend('<th>Checkbox</th>');
    $tbody.find('> tr').each(function(index, element) {
        var $tr = $(element);
        $tr.prepend('<td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="'+index+'">   </td>');
    });
};

$(function() {
    AddCheckboxToTable($('table.goal'));
});
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/dYAkJ/